# How to use SQL count function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show number of count in a Text Box

```
protected void PresentCalculator()
{
    string cur_month = "May";

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(EMP_CODE) FROM 
Attendance where Month ='" + cur_month + "' and EMP_CODE='" + 2222 + "' ", 
con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        txtPresentDay.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.  Do not concatenate SQL queries, you need to use parameterized queries.

Comment: For protection can I use store procedure and class file

Comment: use sql parameters to pass any inputs towards the SQL server. TO have count work, you need a group by clause.

Comment: Learn from Bobby: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Also, you are selecting a single value. No need for a `DataAdapter` and a `DataTable`, use `SQLCommand` and `ExecuteScalar` instead,

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `SqlDataAdapter` use a `SqlCommand`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

and get the value by calling `ExecuteScalar`
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx

Like this:

```
using(var sqlCon = new SqlConnetion())
{
    using(var sqlCommand = sqlCon.CreateCommand())
    {
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(EMP_CODE) FROM Attendance WHERE Month = @curMonth AND EMP_CODE= @empCode";
        command.Parameters.Add("@curMonth", SqlDbType.Int).Value = curMonth;
        command.Parameters.Add("@empCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2222;

        var count = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
        txtPresentDay.Text = Convert.ToString(count);
    }
}
```

I only know little about your database and your requirements, but here a little warning: you are only asking for the month, be sure that is really what you want.

So the attendance will be counted if it was on 2017/5/1, 2016/5/1, 1997/5/1 - since the month is always the same but the year changes.